# Adhoc distribution and Managed App Configuration prior to Volume Purchase Program distribution

Tags: ios, mdm, ad-hoc-distribution, b2b

I am building an application which is to be distributed via the volume purchase program. However to weed out the initial set of bug which could occur I would like to give the customer an adhoc distribution on a couple of devices.

1. Is this allowed by Apple
2. Could they distribute this adhoc delivery via their MDM tot he allowed devices
3. Could they use managed app distribution to configure it.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can do this per Apple's guidelines. You're going to end up burning devices out of your portal with this of course.
2. Yes, the key being the devices are enrolled in their MDM and are listed within the adhoc build.
3. Managed App Configuration is an iOS7+ feature that should be usable pending your MDM supports it AND you app, enterprise or otherwise, supports it as well. Obviously an enterprise app will be more flexible in its config while an App Store app developer will have to tell you which shared keys are supported. Whoever is maintaining the source MDM instance will have to configure those settings and keys specifically for that app.

Comment: Thanks for the information Dan. Question three is about how they configure the app to set the IP address of the server etc. My understanding is that this is possible through a mechanism call managed app configuration. (http://tomasmcguinness.com/2014/03/07/exploring-apples-managedappconfig-demo/). I know this can be done for enterprise apps. I'm assuming it is possible for any app which is deployed through an MDM. Have you any experience of this?

Comment: Got it. The feature is called Managed App Configuration. You may want to edit your question to reflect that name. I've also edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks again Dan for the great responses.